# In Intellij IDEA 14, I have enabled the quick documentation option, and it can't seem to find the documentation. How do I make it find the docs?

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

[image]

Picture of the bug there. I'm coming from Eclipse, so I enabled the inline documentation viewer but it doesn't seem to be picking up anything. Anyone know which file needs to point to what spot?

Comment: Maybe you should import the `JTextField` class first, so IDEA knows where to look for the JavaDoc ...

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I ended up finding the below url which helped with the problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91307/attaching-additional-javadoc-in-intellij-idea