# how can I access spark javadoc or sources from java project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-spark, javadoc

I'm using Spark from a java project on IntelliJ 14 CE. Is there any way to navigate to the Spark sources or javadoc? By default it only shows the rough decompile code without any comment.
I wouldn't mind navigating to the scala code if there was a way to do it. But maybe it would be better to plug in the javadoc, but I cannot find it anywhere

thanks

Comment: I guess I am understanding it incorrectly but Right Mouse Click Go To -> Declaration should do the trick?

Comment: @IliaAptsiauri this takes you only to the decompiled code without javadoc

Comment: afterwards you can press F1. "IntelliJ IDEA recognizes inline documentation created in accordance with Javadoc markup."

Comment: @IliaAptsiauri also tried it. comments do not appear because the bytecode jar does not have any. Comments are available only in scala source code (which intellij does not read by default), or at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/.

Comment: Ok gotcha now, the last try :D, I guess you can attach the documentation by yourself check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91307/attaching-additional-javadoc-in-intellij-idea out might help

Comment: @IliaAptsiauri After attaching https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/ to each spark dependency,  F1 works. Thank you! Go ahead and add it as and answer. Strangely F1 does not work from the decompiled code

Comment: Feel free to retweet https://twitter.com/h_schreiber/status/823789681330503680

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussion in the comments the solution appears to be to just add manually the JavaDoc to desired "Module" or Project.

The detailed answer is located at the following thread [Attaching additional javadoc in Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91307/attaching-additional-javadoc-in-intellij-idea)

> Then select the "Dependencies" tab, select the dependency that's missing the javadoc and click "Edit". In the window that just showed up you see two buttons "Attach Javadoc" and "Specify Javadoc URL". If you have the javadoc in a jar file select the first one, if you want to point to a web site that contains the javadoc select the latest. That's it.

Answer (score 8):

What did the trick to me was to install the Scala plugin for IntelliJ, I was then able to navigate and debug through the spark core (which is written in scala), in spite of the project being in Java, and properly see the Javadoc, which was automatically inferred from the scala source code.
Of course, you also need to have the Spark source code properly setup, easy to do using Gradle or Maven.

Comment: Thnx! Worked for me.

Comment: @FelipeKunzler you're a lifesaver!

Comment: Yeah, same attaching sources jar explicitly was not working. However, this worked. Should have come here before.

Answer (score 1):

In your sbt build file you can always do this:

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % versions('spark) withSources() withJavadoc(),
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % versions('spark) withSources() withJavadoc(),
```

`versions('spark)` is just the version of spark that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

"right click on your pom.xml" -> "Maven" -> then choose "Download Sources and Documentation"

To avoid this in the future: "Preferences" -> "Build, Execution, Deployment" -> "Build Tools" -> "Maven" -> "Importing" -> Check the Automatically download Sources and Documentation boxes.

Credit to Yacov Schondorf and Stephen Boesch from Intellij user forums.