# How to link a Gradle project to the Javadoc of its dependencies?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-16

I have a Gradle project consisting of an Android application module. I cannot figure out how to get the Android application module to link into the Javadoc of its dependencies.

I have specified the following in the project's root-level `build.gradle` file as well the Android application module's `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
```

I can see by inspecting the `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1` folder on my machine that the Javadoc for the dependencies has indeed been downloaded.

However, when I inspect the xml files in the `.idea/libraries` folder in my project, I see that the `JAVADOC` tag is always empty. The `CLASSES` and `SOURCES` tags are non-empty and, of course, link correctly to the classes and sources respectively. How can I get IntelliJ to link to the Javadoc also (so that when I press F1 on one of the dependency's classes or methods I see the Javadoc)?

#### Afterwords

1. I have tried hitting the "Refresh all Gradle projects" button as well as hitting "Invalidate caches / Restart...". That makes no difference.
2. I have tried this on both IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.3 as well as Android Studio 2.2.3. Same problem on both.
3. I am aware that I can see Javadoc for dependencies of my application which have published Sources. The problem is that some of my application's dependencies have published Javadoc but not Sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually specify the JavaDoc location in `Project Structure | Libraries | Specify Documentation URL`. This will populate `JAVADOC` element in the `.idea/libraries` directory. You can point it at a url or download a Javadoc jar.

To get the downloaded jar to work I needed to unzip the jar and point the IntelliJ url to the directory containing the unzipped javadocs. The resulting url would look like `file:///tmp/junit` with unzipped javadocs being inside the junit directory.

[image: Show where to click in the project strucuture]

There is a good answer here [Attaching additional javadoc in Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91307/attaching-additional-javadoc-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying it out but running into some problems. Is it possible to specify a local url because I tried entering the remote url at which the jar exists but IntelliJ is failing to find documentation in there. Probably because it's an Artifactory url that requires username and password? I tried entering a local path that points to the javadoc jar file with the `jar://` protocol (ending with `!/`) and I tried entering the local path of the jar with the `file://` protocol. No luck. In both cases IntelliJ doesn't even add the Javadoc url like in ur screenshot. Please advise.

Comment: To use the Junit javadoc jar I needed to download the jar and then unzip into a empty directory. My path ended up looking like file:///tmp/junit

Comment: Awesome. That worked. Thanks so much. Would be great if IntelliJ could automatically link to the dependency's Javadoc like it does with the Sources. But I'll make a separate question/request for that. This does the job for now. Thanks again.

Comment: Created an IntelliJ feature request [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165338). Anyone reading this... Please upvote if you would like to see that feature added to IntelliJ.