# How should a javadoc file/folder's structure look like?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

I've been seeing all kinds of questions on how to add javadoc to all the popular IDE's but when I try any of those there is still no result. So there must be something wrong with the way I have created the javadoc file/folder.

I've tried adding javadoc to Intellij project like this: [Attaching additional javadoc in Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91307/attaching-additional-javadoc-in-intellij-idea)

My javadoc.jar looks like this:
[files in the javadoc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIfsN.png)

I extracted these files from the source files of the library I'm trying to use. Is there something missing in the file that isn't allowing Intellij to see the javadoc?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "there is still no result"? Javadoc is the generated output form [javadoc tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-135444.html) packaged into a jar archive. You attach it to a library in [library dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configure-library-dialog.html). Note that in case of Maven/Gradle IDE takes the sources/javadoc from the maven repo just as the compiled library classes.

Comment: @Andrey I mean that Intellij doesn't show any documentation when I hover over the classes or functions (I have the option turned on to show them when hovered over). I have used the javadoc tool to extract the documentation. As a result I got a folder containing the files. It looks like the one I have linked in my original question. I placed them all in a jar file and added them through the library dialog.

Comment: Can you provide this library and the javadoc?

Comment: Do you see the javadoc if you select a class/method and use Ctrl-Q ?